# ggplot2 - R: put different colour for my groups in manhattan plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I used to created my manhattan plot this programming:

```
ggplot(subset(data1), aes(CHR, P),group=CHR) +
geom_point(pos = position_jitter(w = 0.45, h = 0.45),
aes(colour =(CHR)))+
scale_x_discrete(limits=c(1:27)) +
theme(legend.position="none")+ ylab("Bayes Factor") +
geom_hline(yintercept=20,colour="red", alpha=I(1/3)) +
geom_hline(yintercept=150,colour="red", alpha=I(3/3))
```

But in this case, each group (as CHR) have a level of blue colour.
But I wanted which each group (each CHR - 27) have a colour.

I tried some function, but did not change the colour:

```
+ scale_fill_manual(name = "Values", values=setNames(colors, 1:8))
```

or

```
    + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

or

```
    + scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

or

```
      + scale_colour_brewer(breaks=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11",
   "12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26",
     "27"), palette = "Set1")
```

or

```
+ d+scale_colour_brewer(breaks=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11",
 "12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26",
 values = c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00",
 "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00","#E69F00", 
"#56B4E9", "#009E73", 
 "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00","#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", 
 "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00","#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73"))
```

Comment: Maybe try to put `group=CHR` inside `aes(...)` in your first line so it reads: `ggplot(subset(data1), aes(CHR, P, group=CHR)) +`

Comment: would be easier to answer is you provided enough data (use `dput`) to make your problem reproducible

Comment: @sinQueso I tried, but with only this not change. The problem, as Feng answer, is the column classification. But, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with your color palette selection. It is because  `CHR` column is numeric, not a factor. You need to convert it first:

```
data1$CHR <- as.factor(data1$CHR)

ggplot(subset(data1), aes(CHR, P, group = CHR)) +
geom_point(pos = position_jitter(w = 0.45, h = 0.45),
aes(colour =(CHR)))
```

Comment: Thank you. But I can change the pallet colour here? For me is "pastel colour", and I want "hot colour". I can do this? @Feng

Comment: Sure. Now you can use `scale_color_manual` or any brewer of palette function as you have tried to pick any color you like.